# Swift Charts LineChart: Display day on x-axis even if the respective γ-value is nill

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, charts

It is my first time using the native Swift Charts framework and I ran into a problem regarding my x-axis of my chart.

First, let me tell you about the chart behaviour I want to achieve:

I want to render a chart that displays weight data of the last seven days (including today), similarly to how the Apple Health app does this in the "week-tab". From the screenshot of Apple Health you can see that the x-Axis always has the last seven days on it, irrespective whether there actually is data for the displayed days. In the left screenshot you see a full week in which all days have valid data. In the right screenshot you see a full week but for the last day ("today") I removed the data. Apple Health still rightly shows the day on the x-axis, it just doesn't use the data point for the LineChart, keeping the x-axis to a fixed 7 days:

Desired x-axis behaviour in Apple Health app:

[image]

Here is my attempt to re-create the described chart behavior:

Every chart data element has a `.date` and optinally an `.averageWeight`:

```swift
struct WeightChartData: Identifiable
{
    var id = UUID()
    var date: Date
    var averageWeight: Double?
}
```

---

I use a data array containing 7 such `WeightChartData` elements, representing the users last 7 days of weight data (including today). Weight data on any day might be `nill` (when no HealthKit data was retrieved for that day). The array is populated with data so that the last element represents "today". Here is my testing/debugging test array (so you can better see the structure of my actual data array):

```swift
var testData: [WeightChartData] =
[
    WeightChartData(date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -6, to: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()))!, averageWeight: 95.1),
    WeightChartData(date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -5, to: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()))!, averageWeight: 94.2),
    WeightChartData(date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -4, to: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()))!, averageWeight: 94.4),
    WeightChartData(date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -3, to: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()))!, averageWeight: nil),
    WeightChartData(date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -2, to: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()))!, averageWeight: 93.5),
    WeightChartData(date: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()))!, averageWeight: 93.6),
    WeightChartData(date: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()),                                                        averageWeight: nil)
]
```

It is important to note that the array might include `WeightChartData`-elements with `.averageWeight == nill`, meaning no weight data exists on those days.

---

This is how I attempted to draw the chart (`WeightViewModel.Data` is my "production" data array containing 7 `WeightChartData`-elements). **Note the conditional `LineMark(...)`:**

```swift
Chart(WeightViewModel.Data)
{ item in
    if item.averageWeight != nil
    {
        LineMark(
            x: .value("Date", item.date, unit: .weekday),
            y: .value("Value", item.averageWeight!)
        )
    }
}
```

I use these two modifiers to ensure my y-Axis scale is around the min and max `.averageWeight` of the data array.

```swift
.chartYScale(
    domain: [ getBottomRange(), getTopRange() ]
)

.chartYAxis
{
    AxisMarks(
        position: .leading,
        values: .automatic(desiredCount: getYMarkCount())
    )
}
```

This (γ-axis-customization) works as expected. Still, here are `getBottomRange()`, `getTopRange()` and `getYMarkCount() if you think these might cause my x-axis-related issue:

```swift
func getTopRange() -> Int
{
    return Int(round(WeightViewModel.maxWeightData()?.averageWeight ?? 0.0) + 1.0)
}
    
func getBottomRange() -> Int
{
    return Int(round(WeightViewModel.minWeightData()?.averageWeight ?? 0.0) - 1.0)
}

func getYMarkCount() -> Int
{        
    return abs(getTopRange() - getBottomRange())
}
```

---

For the x-axis, I use this to create one `AxisMark(...)` for every day (so 7 elements on the x-Axis, irrespective of the elements containing weight data or nil, like in Apple Health):

```swift
.chartXAxis
{
    AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .day))
    { date in
        AxisGridLine()
        AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.weekday(.narrow), centered: true)
    }
}
```

---

**Let me now show you what happen's if one day has `.averageWeight == nil`:**

- If all of WeightViewModel.Data elements have valid `.averageWeight`: the graph draws correctly (meaning drawing all 7 days on the x-Axis):

[image]

- If an element (that is not the first or last element) has `.averageWeight == nil`, the chart rightly skips this y-value while stil showing the day on the x-Axis:

[image]

like in Apple Health. In this example only the second to last element
has `.averageWeight == nil`.

- The problem is when the **first or last element’s** `.averageWeight == nil`. Again, because the `LineMark(..)` is only called `if item.averageWeight != nil`, this first or last data point is skipped. Only this time, because it’s the first or last element, my x-Axis scale gets disrupted. Instead of still showing 7 days, it will now remove the day that has no weightData from the chart, resulting in only having 6 days on the x-Axis:

[image]

In this example I set the last element's `.averageWeight`to `nil`.
**Note that Thursday is no longer on the x-Axis**.

This is not all too surprising, as when the first or last element get’s skippid, the chart doesn’t even know that it has to display 7 dates. But I still want the day (that has no .averageWeight) to be shown on the chart’s x-Axis (as my x-Axis should always have 7 elements representing the last 7 days).

How would one achieve the described chart behavior of always showing the full week even when having optional data that might be `nil`?

Thank you for reading all of this and trying to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said, I'm only using Swift/SwiftUI a couple of weeks now, but apparently you can use **[.chartXScale(domain:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/chartxscale(domain:type:))** with a closed date range...

> **domain:**
> The possible data values along the x axis in the chart. You can define the domain with a ClosedRange for number or Date values (e.g., 0 ... 500) . . . [- Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/chartxscale(domain:type:))

I got my intended behavior oddly only after adding one day after the last element using:

```
.chartXScale(domain: WeightViewModel.Data.first!.date ... Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: WeightViewModel.Data.last!.date)!
```